# Odd behavior with react-modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-modal

I'm trying to build a quiz that uses `react-modal` to provides hints. I will need multiple modals inside the quiz. I'm new to React so it's quite possible that I'm making a simple mistake.

I'm not sure it matters, but I've built this using `create-react-app`.

My App.js looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import HintModal from './hintModal';
import Modal from 'react-modal';
import './App.css';

Modal.setAppElement('#root');

class App extends Component {

  state = {
    modalIsOpen: false,
    hint: ''
  };

  openModal = (hint) => {
    this.setState({ modalIsOpen: true,  hint: hint });
  }

  closeModal = () => {
    this.setState({ modalIsOpen: false, hint: '' });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
      <h1>Modal Test</h1>
      <h2>First Modal</h2>
      <HintModal 
        modalIsOpen={this.state.modalIsOpen}
        openModal={this.openModal}
        closeModal={this.closeModal}
        hint="mango"
      />
      <hr />
      <h2>Second Modal</h2>
      <HintModal 
        modalIsOpen={this.state.modalIsOpen}
        openModal={this.openModal}
        closeModal={this.closeModal}
        hint="banana"
      />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

hintModal.jsx looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Modal from 'react-modal';

const HintModal = (props) => {

    const {openModal, modalIsOpen, closeModal, hint} = props;

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <button onClick={ () => openModal(hint) }>Open Modal</button>
            <Modal
                isOpen={modalIsOpen}
                onRequestClose={closeModal}
                contentLabel="Example Modal"
            >
                <h2>Hint</h2>
                <p>{hint}</p>
                <button onClick={closeModal}>Close</button>
            </Modal>
            <p>We should see: {hint}</p>
         </React.Fragment>
    );

};

export default HintModal;
```

Here's the problem: I need the content of the modal to change based on the `hint` prop passed to HintModal. When I output `hint` from outside `<Modal>`, it behaves as expected, displaying the value of the prop. But when I output `hint` within `<Modal>`, it returns "banana" (the value of the `hint` prop for the second instance of HintModal) when either modal is activated.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You will open the modal with the `banana` hint every time since you are controlling both modals with the same state variable. [You could instead have a separate variable for every modal](https://codesandbox.io/s/y0lpo589mz), or you could have one modal that just renders the props given to it and change the props depending on what question is active.

Answer (score 0):

You are controlling all of your modals with the same piece of state and the same functions to open and close the modal.

You need to either have just one modal and then dynamically render the message inside it or you need to store a `modalIsOpen` variable in your state for every single modal.